# Throttle scroll event to add box-shadow

Tags: jquery, performance, scroll, coffeescript, throttling

When I scroll an element on the page, I add a shadow to another specified element to visually show the user that the page is scrolled, generally when viewing long lists.

```
# HTML
<header id="header">
  header...
</div>
<main data-behavior="scroll-shadow" data-scroll-shadow-element="#header">
  ...
</main>

# CoffeeScript using jQuery
$("[data-behavior~='scroll-shadow']").on "scroll", (e) ->
  $trigger = $(this)
  $target = $($trigger.attr("data-scroll-shadow-element"))

  if $trigger.scrollTop()
    $target.addClass("scroll-shadow-active")
  else
    $target.removeClass("scroll-shadow-active")
```

This code works just fine, and it adds/removes the CSS class which shows the box-shadow.

However, I know that attaching events to scroll is a bad idea for performance reasons.

As I was looking into this, though, I came across a few different solutions and I wasn't sure which was best for this type of use-case.

**Debouce**

Seems possible, as it would grab a group of scroll events and fire the handler once for those groups so it doesn't fire every time.  However, it seems that this solution wouldn't actually add the styled shadow until the user stops scrolling.  So if the user scrolled from top to bottom of a very long list, they wouldn't see the shadow until several seconds later.

**Throttle**

This seems like the better way to go, basically only execute a set number of events instead of every one (maybe like only 1/4 of the scroll events actually trigger the handler).

---

Since I'm not a JavaScript performance expert of any sort, I wasn't sure what a better option would be.  I'm also looking at using Lodash as a JS utility library since they already have tested code for throttling/etc.

Is throttling the best solution performance wise for this particular type of event handling?  What are ways to add shadows for scrolled elements in a performant fashion?

Answer (score 0):

How I understand "debouncing events" is to be selective on these... Instead of taking them all.

On scroll, I usually take the first event and ignore the others.
That, in a performance perspective... Because, here, that only is an `addClass()`. But it could be something else which to repeatedly call would be bad.

So I use a "flag" or a counter like here.

Then, a `setTimeout()` resets that flag or timer when the user has finished scrolling.

```js
var shadowTarget;
var scrollTimeout;
var eventCount=0;
$("[data-behavior~='scroll-shadow']").on("scroll", function(){

  eventCount++;
  if(eventCount==1){
    trigger = $(this);
    shadowTarget = $(trigger.attr("data-scroll-shadow-element"));

    console.log("Adding the class.");
    shadowTarget.addClass("scroll-shadow-active");
  }

  // setting a new timeout at each scroll event.
  clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
  scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Removing the class.");
    shadowTarget.removeClass("scroll-shadow-active");
    eventCount=0;
  },500);


});
```

```css
header{
  background-color: cyan;
}
main{
  overflow-Y: scroll;
  height:600px;
}
.scroll-shadow-active{
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<header id="header">
  header...
</header>
<main data-behavior="scroll-shadow" data-scroll-shadow-element="#header">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sollicitudin leo eu bibendum aliquam. Curabitur aliquet eros lectus, et molestie nisi tempor vel. Quisque mollis, sapien hendrerit accumsan pellentesque, quam quam vestibulum orci, nec ornare diam turpis ut purus. Cras ut quam ut nibh sollicitudin scelerisque. Nunc volutpat mauris sed porta lacinia. Vivamus pharetra eget tortor nec venenatis. Vivamus nec velit ut felis consectetur ullamcorper. Suspendisse id dictum enim. Nulla ut volutpat nisi, vitae tempor diam. Proin mattis dui ante, fermentum lacinia ex vulputate at. Donec tristique eget urna vel convallis. Mauris ac elit ut orci pretium faucibus ac sit amet justo.
  </p>
  <p>
    Suspendisse gravida sodales lorem, sit amet posuere nunc semper et. Proin euismod at arcu in suscipit. Quisque eu efficitur nunc, quis hendrerit orci. Mauris a erat quis ante aliquam imperdiet posuere ac dui. Nam sit amet consectetur nunc. Donec risus ex, convallis eget orci tristique, rhoncus auctor tortor. Aliquam sit amet fermentum nisl. Morbi vel ipsum et nisl tristique fringilla nec sed ipsum. Aenean aliquet purus id bibendum tempus. Suspendisse auctor pretium augue, a tincidunt sapien vehicula quis. Ut eu sagittis turpis. Nulla rhoncus felis nibh, in viverra magna sagittis congue. Integer tempus ultricies viverra. Sed a aliquet velit.
  </p>
  <p>
    Cras sagittis, dolor accumsan commodo condimentum, tellus lorem bibendum diam, in consequat augue quam nec est. Quisque id eros tortor. Ut ex risus, vehicula quis cursus a, efficitur convallis erat. Maecenas egestas lobortis maximus. Phasellus varius, ipsum in maximus ultrices, orci lectus tincidunt magna, vel vestibulum urna turpis ac leo. Nulla nulla massa, consequat non vulputate imperdiet, volutpat dapibus orci. Etiam consequat volutpat est, id tempus turpis venenatis vitae. Praesent arcu erat, porta molestie neque non, ultrices dignissim sem. Suspendisse potenti. Duis nec mauris commodo libero maximus egestas. Sed laoreet maximus tellus semper accumsan.
  </p>
  <p>
    In hendrerit molestie blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nullam in ipsum urna. Maecenas in ante nisi. Integer porta molestie enim, sit amet scelerisque mauris fringilla elementum. Phasellus at elit mattis, scelerisque ligula et, imperdiet leo. Suspendisse nec dignissim augue. Cras neque turpis, tempus vel tortor sit amet, commodo laoreet augue. Aliquam ac dui vel lorem facilisis tristique non non urna. Cras pharetra mauris id aliquet luctus. Morbi sit amet felis a lectus maximus lacinia. Sed quam elit, imperdiet eu rhoncus in, scelerisque sed arcu. Aliquam feugiat ultrices finibus. Suspendisse a semper risus, gravida laoreet lacus. In fermentum auctor volutpat. Nullam egestas, lorem eget imperdiet semper, elit nisl aliquet neque, nec mollis erat lacus ut nibh.
  </p>
  <p>
    Ut sit amet ex iaculis, vestibulum urna id, dictum elit. Nunc semper semper lacus at feugiat. Nam viverra orci vel risus vulputate, sed fringilla turpis ultrices. Vivamus pulvinar, mi in bibendum scelerisque, nunc augue laoreet sem, vitae posuere ipsum mauris vel turpis. Aliquam quis nulla maximus ligula eleifend aliquet ut a neque. Cras lobortis id ante quis sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In maximus quam at rhoncus venenatis. Sed tempus nec urna vel tempus. Mauris aliquam, risus id mollis commodo, dolor tortor porta augue, in consequat purus velit nec ante.
  </p>
  <p>
    Proin tempus pharetra nisl ut rhoncus. Fusce dapibus tincidunt lobortis. Donec dolor nisi, posuere ut ullamcorper a, molestie ut enim. Sed quis felis accumsan, pellentesque nunc at, vestibulum dolor. Pellentesque quis ex nec ex tincidunt sodales. Pellentesque eget justo nisl. Nullam rutrum ligula sed libero tempor ullamcorper. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam enim felis, cursus sed sem a, gravida consectetur diam. Ut accumsan diam ut tempor fringilla. Etiam at ex lacus. Morbi tortor mauris, blandit sed mi ut, eleifend tempus magna.
  </p>
  <p>
    Maecenas at rutrum ante. Aenean eu sapien in sem hendrerit facilisis dictum vel sem. Ut laoreet ligula quis risus congue commodo. Donec tempor, turpis sollicitudin vulputate auctor, nunc mi maximus lectus, ornare lobortis metus neque a nibh. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed id tempor purus. Donec ipsum mauris, molestie at posuere non, scelerisque ac massa. Etiam scelerisque tempus ante, finibus dictum ante gravida eget. Suspendisse convallis risus vel velit ornare, vitae aliquam purus dictum. Nullam suscipit magna tellus, a accumsan elit viverra in. Etiam rutrum turpis non lorem condimentum viverra.
  </p>
  <p>
    Maecenas cursus eros sed urna laoreet pulvinar. Sed a consectetur felis, consectetur gravida enim. Etiam varius ac ligula vel ultrices. Proin et lectus euismod, molestie purus ut, hendrerit mi. Suspendisse lobortis ipsum sem. Quisque nec augue quis lectus egestas consequat. Donec in arcu in mi feugiat congue. Nam porta augue venenatis diam auctor, quis aliquam dolor pulvinar. Sed vitae nibh nec ligula congue facilisis ac eget felis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent tellus arcu, commodo a vestibulum et, pulvinar vel lacus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Quisque vel elit vitae turpis sollicitudin fringilla. Quisque iaculis dignissim sodales. Vivamus in nisi id turpis commodo pretium ornare ac enim. Nulla eu ex lobortis, lacinia mauris sed, consectetur diam. Donec at metus vel metus tincidunt blandit. Donec molestie purus quis sapien rhoncus euismod. Donec gravida, nunc quis consequat ornare, augue leo vestibulum eros, ac euismod lectus ex non mi.
  </p>
  <p>
    Vestibulum quis libero sed risus consectetur porttitor sed quis nunc. Duis malesuada erat posuere erat suscipit, nec commodo augue faucibus. Nulla euismod diam eget sollicitudin fermentum. Sed ullamcorper tempus augue et tempus. Mauris non neque justo. Aenean tristique mauris nibh, sit amet lobortis est tristique ut. Aliquam nibh ex, varius vel consequat nec, vehicula non turpis.
  </p>
</main>
```

As you can see... There is no more than ONE "Adding the class." in console.
;)

Comment: Instead of `<p>Lorem ipsum give me a breaksum</p>` N times - you could simply `<p style="height:300vh;border:4px dashed #000;">Y'all</p>`